# jQuery contextMenu: Submenu is aligned far from main menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, contextmenu

I am using a jQuery data table and on right-click, I want to display a menu with a submenu.
The menu is displayed properly, however, the sub menu is aligned far from the main menu

[image]

I am creating list for menu and submenu

HTML is like:

```js
//Context menu
$(document).contextmenu({
  delegate: ".divRightClick",
  menu: "#callOptions"

});
```

```css
.ui-icon {
  background-position: left !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}

.ui-icon-dial {
  background-image: url('/images/BOContact_16x16.png') !important;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ui-menu-item-wrapper .ui-state-active .ui-icon {
  background-image: url('/images/BOContact_16x16.png') !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: #FCFDFD !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: no-display;
  width: 100px !important;
}

.ui-icon-work {
  background-image: url('/images/work.png') !important;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ui-icon-home {
  background-image: url('/images/telephone.png') !important;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ui-icon-cell {
  background-image: url('/images/Phone_16x16.png') !important;
  margin-top: 57px;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
  margin-left: 25px !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.ui-menu .ui-front {
  margin-left: -10px !important;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  background: #FCFDFD !important;
  /*font-weight: bold !important;*/
  /*color: #ffffff !important;*/
  /* border: 1px solid #580201;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: no-display;
  width: 80% !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.ui-icon .ui-icon-work .ui-menu-item-wrapper .ui-state-active {
  background-image: url('/images/work.png') !important;
  /*font-weight: bold !important;*/
  /*color: #ffffff !important;*/
  /* border: 1px solid #580201;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: no-display;
  width: 80% !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
  border: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.18.1/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>



<body>
  <div class="divRightClick"></div>

  <ul id="callOptions" style="width: 144px; border: 1px solid #000000 !important; display:none;">
    <li>
      <div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-dial"></span>Dial</div>
      <ul aria-expanded="false" class="clsCallMenu" style="top: 10px; left: 120.5px; display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
        <li data-command="Work">
          <div><span class="ui-icon-work" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Work</div>
        </li>
        <li data-command="Home">
          <div><span class="ui-icon-home" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Home</div>
        </li>
        <li data-command="Cell">
          <div><span class="ui-icon-cell" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Cell</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><span class="ui-icon "></span>Quick Email</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><span class="ui-icon "></span>Refresh</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

I tried to add my code into a snippet, however, I am getting a script error, and looks like contextMenu.js is giving a 404 error. In my actual code, I am not getting this error

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Upon further investigation, you must include both jQuery and jQuery UI to make use of this library. See the Git: https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/wiki

Comment: The primary issue is that your CSS Code is creating additional margins and is causing the sub-menus to be pushed further to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. It includes a number of CSS changes.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".divRightClick",
    menu: "#callOptions"
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-icon {
  background-position: left;
  background-image: none;
}

.ui-icon-dial {
  background-image: url('/images/BOContact_16x16.png');
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ui-menu-item-wrapper .ui-state-active .ui-icon {
  background: #FCFDFD url('/images/BOContact_16x16.png');
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-icon-work {
  background-image: url('/images/work.png');
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ui-icon-home {
  background-image: url('/images/telephone.png');
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ui-icon-cell {
  background-image: url('/images/Phone_16x16.png');
  margin-top: 57px;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  background: #FCFDFD;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  color: #000000;
}

.ui-icon .ui-icon-work .ui-menu-item-wrapper .ui-state-active {
  background-image: url('/images/work.png') !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  color: #000000;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
  border: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.18.1/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>

<div class="divRightClick">
  Right Click Me
</div>
<ul id="callOptions">
  <li>
    <div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-dial"></span>Dial</div>
    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="clsCallMenu" style="top: 10px; left: 120.5px; display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
      <li data-command="Work">
        <div><span class="ui-icon-work" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Work</div>
      </li>
      <li data-command="Home">
        <div><span class="ui-icon-home" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Home</div>
      </li>
      <li data-command="Cell">
        <div><span class="ui-icon-cell" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></span>Cell</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span class="ui-icon "></span>Quick Email</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span class="ui-icon "></span>Refresh</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> The `overflow` property has the following values:
>
> - `visible` - Default. The overflow is not clipped. The content renders outside the element's box
> - `hidden` - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible
> - `scroll` - The overflow is clipped, and a scrollbar is added to see the rest of the content
> - `auto` - Similar to scroll, but it adds scrollbars only when necessary

In your CSS, you use `no-display` which is not supported by `overflow`.

I also removed a lot of the `!important` parts, as they should not be needed.

I was unable to load the images due to the local relative paths, yet the spacing seems correct now.